# javascript style is not working on splited strings

Tags: javascript, methods, split, styles

When i split two words using split() method, i can't style it with pure javasript. My intention is to change color of second word. Is anyone knows the solution. The code is as follows. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<p id="demo">Better Choice</p>
```

Javascript:

```
let a = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
let b = a.split(" ");
let c = b[1];
c.style.color="red"; // this is not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C at the moment is just the work Choice it is not an HTML element so you cannot add style. If you want to add style you need to turn it into an element and then style it.

```
let a = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
let b = a.split(" ");
let c = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = b[0] + " <span style='color:red'>" + b[1]+ "</span>";
```

Once you do the a.split(" ") you lose access to the element itself so you need to get it again for C.

You could also do this

```
let a = document.getElementById('demo');
let b = a.innerHTML.split(" ");
let c = a.innerHTML = b[0] + " <span style='color:red'>" + b[1]+ "</span>";
```

Also if you want the color red exposed to edit dynamically you could use String Literals like this.

```js
let a = document.getElementById('demo');
let b = a.innerHTML.split(" ");
let color = "red";
let c = a.innerHTML = `${b[0]} <span style='color:${color}'>${b[1]}</span>`;
```

```html
<p id="demo">Better Choice</p>
```

Comment: Hi, Zodsmar, Thank you very much for your Awesome answer with detailed description!

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'c' does hold only part of the innerHTML value. If you dont want the entire 'a' element to change color and only the second part, insert a span element for that like this:

```
let a = document.getElementById('demo');
let b = a.innerHTML.split(" ");
let c = b[1];
a.innerHTML = `${b[0]} <span style="color:red">${c}</span>`
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/i4irsh/pen/OJRPyJe)

Comment: Thank You very much Irshad for your answer!